# SQLAlchemy - loading user by username

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pylons

Just diving into pylons here, and am trying to get my head around the basics of SQLALchemy.  I have figured out how to load a record by id:

```
user_q = session.query(model.User)
user = user_q.get(user_id)
```

But how do I query by a specific field (i.e. username)?  I assume there is a quick way to do it with the model rather than hand-building the query.  I think it has something with the `add_column()` function on the query object, but I can't quite figure out how to use it.  I've been trying stuff like this, but obviously it doesn't work:

```
user_q = meta.Session.query(model.User).add_column('username'=user_name)
user = user_q.get()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you want something like this:

```
user = meta.Session.query(model.User).filter_by(name=user_name).first()
```

Which is short for this:

```
user = meta.Session.query(model.User).filter(model.User.name=user_name).first()
```

[Here's more documentation](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/tutorial.html#querying)

If you change `first()` into `one()` it will raise an exception if there isn't a user (if you want to assert one exists).

I highly suggest reading through both [Object Relational Tutorial](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/tutorial.html) as well as the and the [SQL Expression Language Tutorial](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/tutorial.html).